# Converting server timezone to localtime momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs

My server is in  EDT -4 and I'm trying to convert dates in my databse into user's local timezone using momentj. I tried everything but it doesn't work.

These are things I tried:

```
//1
var servertime= array[data].time
var localtime= moment(servertime).toDate();
var time = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
//Actual Database time: 2015-10-20 12:42:47    Output:2015-10-20 12:42:47

//2
var servertime= array[data].time
var localtime= moment.utc(servertime).toDate();
var time = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
//Actual Database time: 2015-10-20 12:42:47    Output:2015-10-20 12:42:47
```

It seems moment doesn't change it at all.

For example when UTC time on server is : October 20, 2015 17:29
my computer clock UTC +1 is october 20, 2015 7:30

Comment: "it doesn't work" is never enough information. What are the inputs, desired outputs and actual outputs? How are you obtaining the data to start with? Why does your *server* time zone matter at all? (Unless you've stored the dates using your server's time zone, which would almost certainly be a mistake...)

Comment: Presumably somewhere you have to tell moment that the server time is EDT? You don't do anything like that in the first example and in the second you claim it's UTC.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added input output. It seems it doesn't even change the time

Comment: Well you've shown what `localtime` is but you haven't shown how you've worked out what `servertime` is.

Comment: @JonSkeet servertime is the time stored in my database because I'm using current_timestamp as default in my mysql. So actual databse time is my server time.

Comment: Well, that's what you think. But you haven't shown how you're validating what value that is in Javascript. Why don't you just dump `servertime` and `localtime` to the console? (We don't know exactly what `array[data].time` is, for example.)

Comment: @JonSkeet yes I just used console on array[data].time and the values are the same

Comment: @JonSkeet I also wrote an example of current time and my computer clock

Comment: But you still haven't shown how you're obtaining the array to start with. Maybe it's already in UTC, for example, so that calling `utc` on it won't make any difference. Basically, we have no chance of reproducing the problem at the moment, because you're just giving us scraps of information.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing almost everything correct. Your main problem is you're storing the javascript date object in your `localtime` variable.

```
//I'm assuming your this is your server time. This assumes your server time is in UTC.
var servertime= '2015-10-20 12:42:47';
//Create a utc moment, then convert it to the local time. localtime is a momentjs object.
var localtime = moment.utc(servertime).local();
//format the local time
var time = localtime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

`.utc()` and `.local()` convert a time from being displayed in UTC and local time respectively. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/ for more information.

Comment: I fixed it another way so I cannot test it but thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the time that was being inserted in my database was not unix time so I changed my php code to instead of current_timestamp in mysql use php time() function. Then I used date('c',mytimedata) in php to make it in proper format for using in moment. Then simply used:

```
 var localTime  = moment(array[data].time).toDate();
```